# POST Status Code: 404 Not Found ERROR: Cannot POST /api/users/signup

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a project using react.js in the frontend and node.js in the backend. I keep getting a `POST Status Code: 404 Not Found` error in my code for my signup page. Specifically, I'm getting: `Cannot POST /api/users/signup`. I've gone over my code a number of times, and I can't figure out what could be causing this error. I would really appreciate any help or advice on why this could be occurring. Thank you!

Frontend:

SignInScreen:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {signup} from "../actions/userActions";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'


export default function SignupScreen(props) {
      const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
      const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
      const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

     console.log(email, password, confirmPassword)

      const userSignUp = useSelector((state) => state.userSignUp);
      const { userInfo, loading, error } = userSignUp;
    
      let navigate = useNavigate()

      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
          alert('Password and confirm password do not match');
        } else {
          dispatch(signup( email, password));
          navigate ('/onboarding')
        }

        }

    
      return (
        <div className="auth">
            <h2>CREATE ACCOUNT</h2>
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <input
                    type="email"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="email"
                    required={true}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
                <input
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="password"
                    required={true}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
                 <input
                    type="password"
                    id="password-check"
                    name="password-check"
                    placeholder="confirm password"
                    required={true}
                    onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
                <input className="secondary-button" type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

userActions.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import {
  USER_SIGNUP_FAIL,
  USER_SIGNUP_REQUEST,
  USER_SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
} from '../constants/userConstants';


export const signup = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: USER_SIGNUP_REQUEST, payload: { email, password } });
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post('/api/users/signup', {
        email,
        password,
      });
      dispatch({ type: USER_SIGNUP_SUCCESS, payload: data });
      dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data });
      localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_SIGNUP_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

backend:

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {v4} from 'uuid';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import userRouter from './routers/userRouter.js';

dotenv.config();

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/TC', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    /*useCreateIndex: true,*/
});

app.use('/api/users', userRouter);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server is ready');
})



app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

userRouter.js

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import User from '../models/userModel.js';
import { generateToken, isAdmin, isAuth } from '../utils.js';

const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.post(
    '/signup',
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
        const user = new User({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8),
        });
        const createdUser = await user.save();
        res.send({
            _id: createdUser._id,
            email: createdUser.email,
            isAdmin: createdUser.isAdmin,
            token: generateToken(createdUser),
        });
    }),
);

export default userRouter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the localhost in your axios call:
instead of:

```
const { data } = await Axios.post('/api/users/signup', {
...
```

try:

```
const { data } = await Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup', {
```